# Large file uploads fail with access denied

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, electron, multer

We're implementing an API, where a large file is to be uploaded locally to the main server.

Everything works fine until we try uploading large files (>= 4GB); Those fail immediately before even getting to the route, which leads us to believe the problem is in the client.
`net:ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

For server side, we're using Node (v7.4.0) with express (4.14.0) for server side, `Multer` to handle file transfers. for client side it's electron (v1.4.14) and Angular (v1.5.8), as well as metronic which uses jQuery.

Code for client side:

```
 $scope.uploadVideo = function() {
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', file);

        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "API URL",
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        }).then(console.log);
}
```

So, is there a better way of doing this?

We came up with a few different solutions for this, including:
1. serving the video files statically from the client side and asking the server to download them
2. using FTP/SCP or other protocols

but would really prefer to just use angular and not get into setting up a node server inside of the Electron application.

Update: this error occurs on one of our computers but not the other one. The only noticeable difference I have noticed is that one computer, the one on which is doesn't work, runs Ubuntu on a newer kernel (~4.4.0) while  the other runs kernel ~3.19

Comment: It would be more efficient to POST the file directly instead of using the FormData API. The base64 encoding of multipart/formdata has  33% extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that